# # Error: MongoDB Deploying App in Render.com website

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, backend, render

I have this error:

```
`Error: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/@mongodb-js/saslprep/dist/node.js'
at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1181:15)
at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1169:15)
at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:591:14)
at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:668:31)
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1130:27)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/scram.js:4:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14) {code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',path: '/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/@mongodb-js/saslprep/package.json'}`
```

#### running into the live board report of render.com

Here it is what i want to do:

- 1/ deploy the back-end Node app related to a restaurant online in render.com
- 2/ deploy my react-app in vercel

But i got issue trying 1/(the first step). The issue given above

#### I Tried to :

- delete `node_modules` package and reinstall all the dependencies
- delete `dist` folder and rebuild it using `npm run build` command set in script of **package.json**
- update repository on github based on these **change**

But Nothing seems to solve the problem

I don't know what i'm doing wrong . here is my :

### package.json file

```
`{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "backend\\ bridge between mongoDb and client frontend app",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "build": "babel src -d dist",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js",
    "both-dev": " concurrently \"npm run dev\" \"npm --prefix ../client/ run dev\" "
    },
  "author": "Gerard",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
  "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
  "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "date-fns": "^3.0.6",
  "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
  "express": "^4.19.1",
  "express-jwt": "^8.4.1",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
  "moment": "^2.30.1",
  "mongoose": "^8.2.3",
  "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
  "qs": "^6.12.0",
  "validator": "^13.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.24.1",
  "@babel/core": "^7.24.3",
  "@babel/node": "^7.23.9",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.3",
  "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
  "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
  "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  }
}`
```

And Here Below the work tree of my app:

```
`
tds-restaurant
   |
   |_ _ .github
   |
   |_ _ client ---
                 |
                 |_ _ node_modules
                 |
                 |_ _ src
                 |
                 |_ _ env.local
                 |
                 |_ _ eslintrc.js
                 |
                 |_ _ .gitignore
                 |
                 |_ _ index.html
                 |
                 |_ _ package-lock.json
                 |
                 |_ _ package.json
                 |
                 |_ _ README.md
   |             |
   |             |_ _ vite.config.js
   |
   |
   |_ _ server ---
                 |
                 | _ _dist
                 |
                 |_ _ node_modules
                 |
                 |_ _ src
                 |
                 |_ _ env
                 |
                 |_ _ .gitignore
                 |
                 |_ _ package-lock.json
                 |
                 |_ _ package.json
```

Please Any Help how to solve that matter will help me finally deploy app.
Thanks you for your time.